# socket.io best way to track if a user is online

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I need to update some client side stuff if a user has a socket connection.

Currently I am broadcasting to everyone when a user connects he is "logged in"

---

**Client side** (could do it server side and get the same result)

```
// announce to everyone the user is online
socket.on('connect', function() {
  socket.emit('im online');
});
```

**Server side**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on("im online", function (data) {
        // announce the online status of a new user
        socket.broadcast.emit('connected user',  {"name": socket.handshake.headers.user.username});
    });

});
```

The problem is, now I load the page I let everyone know I am "online" because that loading of the page triggers the event, but if I am idol and another user reloads his/her page nothing is triggered on my end, so there is no indication I am online.

So I am thinking server side I can just capture an array of all the users who made it to the `connection` and send that array down to any new clients connecting and use that to compare to the users friend list to see if any username matches (usernames are 100% unique in each case BTW)

Then when a user disconnects I can just remove it from the array and let the client know.

This would be my solution, but it seems highly ineffective and I am hoping there is a better solution.

Comment: You will almost certainly want your latter approach of tracking the currently connected users on the server.  When a new user connects, send them the full list of all clients, but send everyone else a single UserConnected/UserDisconnected notification and let connected users update their local lists.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily broadcast the disconnect events as well:

```
socket.on("disconnect", function (data) {
    // announce the offline status of a new user
    socket.broadcast.emit('disconnected user',  {"name": socket.handshake.headers.user.username});
});
```

Th disconnect event is automatically generated on server side when the client disconnects.

On the other hand probably you have to store on server side all the connected users, because otherwise the newly connected users wouldn't be notified about the already connected others.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly the problem `"On the other hand probably you have to store on server side all the connected users, because otherwise the newly connected users wouldn't be notified about the already connected others."`

There might be 100 users, but I am only friends with 3, so now I am sending an array of 100 to the client and checking which friends exist client side.

Comment: I already know about the disconnect event, the problem lies inside what I just quoted. I am trying to figure out a solution that best stores this server side and communicates it.

Comment: You can filter the friends on server side and send only the filtered list to the clients when they connect, but later you can send only the connected/disconnected events.